# How do I complete a 3-legged authorization from a front-end application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

I am having trouble setting up a 3-legged authorization to connect to Autodesk BIM360 set up on my front-end. The back-end (localhost:8080) works, e.g. simple interface that can access and display data from BIM360, but I cannot get the front-end (localhost:3000) to work. I am able to get the 2-legged authorization to work, but since the 3-legged requires a log in, and I am not sure how to approach this.

For the 2-legged OAuth (on the front-end) I used:

```
const getToken = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url_base + 'api/forge/oauth2lo/token');
  //console.log(data.access_token);
  return data.access_token;
};
```

But the 3-legged set-up is more involved. First, an OAuth class is set up:

```
class OAuth {
  constructor(session) {
    this._session = session;
  }

  getClient(scopes = config.scopes.internal) {
    const { client_id, client_secret, callback_url } = config.credentials;
    return new AuthClientThreeLegged(
      client_id,
      client_secret,
      callback_url,
      scopes
    );
  }
...
```

and the relevant routes:

```
...
router.get('/callback/oauth', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  const { code } = req.query;
  const oauth = new OAuth(req.session);
  try {
    await oauth.setCode(code);
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

router.get('/oauth/url', (req, res) => {
  const url =
    'https://developer.api.autodesk.com' +
    '/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code' +
    '&client_id=' +
    config.credentials.client_id +
    '&redirect_uri=' +
    config.credentials.callback_url +
    '&scope=' +
    config.scopes.internal.join(' ');
  res.end(url);
});
...
```

On the front-end I have tried calling the `'/oauth/url'` path, and it takes me to the login screen, but the login session remains on the back-end (on localhost:8080) and therefore can't access BIM360 data on the front-end.

My question is, how can I login to an Autodesk account on the front-end, and complete the 3-legged authorization to be able to call BIM360 APIs from the back-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is more common to handle the 3-legged auth using the [Authorization Code Grant](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) on the server side, you can use an alternative, "Implicit Grant" 3-legged authentication from the client: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit. That way, after your user logs in, Autodesk will redirect them to your callback URL like so:

```
https://your.custom.app/callback#access_token=<token>&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=<seconds>
```

And your client side JavaScript code can then extract the access code like so:

```js
   var params = {},
       queryString = location.hash.substring(1),
       regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g,
       m;
   while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
     params[m[1]] = m[2];
   }
   alert("your access token is : " + params["access_token"]);
```

Comment: Does this mean I will need 2 registered Forge apps? Since the redirect uri must match the app's registration (which is currently the server).

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to have both server-side and client-side 3-legged authentication. You should just pick one. Typically the 3-legged auth is handled on the server side, and the access token is then stored in a cookie session (as explained in this tutorial: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/3legged/).